# Is an AC current in low frequency as DC current?

Tags: power-supply, ac

I applied to current 1: 3.5 v  100 Hr amplitude 1 and 2: 3.5 v 0.1 Hr amplitude

What is the current with 0.1 Hr as a Dc current?

I used an AC electrical power supply and applied to forms of electrical current as described above (square wave) for 10 minutes on human stem cells.

Can I report 0.1 Hr as a DC current and 100 Hr as an AC current? Is it scientifically problematic?

Comment: Answer: It depends. Clean up your question, give more information - perhaps a schematic. What are you applying this to? How? I assume your 100Hr means you have a period of 100 hours? But unless you more clearly state what, it's hard for anyone to help you

Comment: Is this a question like "when is AC not AC"?

Comment: I quit at the first word.  Not gonna read something this sloppy. -1 for the disrespect.

Comment: @alirahmani No, if its not constant its AC.

Comment: @laptop: By "fixing" the OP's question, you are depriving others of the information that he is thumbing his nose at us.  You didn't actually fix anything, just covered it up.  Only the OP can truly

Comment: Thats not what stack exchange would dictate: https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: Its going to be closed anyway

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a question about electricity, but about language.

If you look at a wire, then at any instant you can assign a value to the current flowing. Now, is that part of an AC current, or a DC current?

It all depends on your time frame. If you look at the wire for some time, say 1 minute, and the current doesn't change, then many folks would say it's DC. If that current was the output of a tide-level meter, and you looked at for a month, then many folks would say it was AC.

When working on a signal generator that was specified up to 6GHz, we often used to rag the lower frequency designers by saying things like '30MHz, that's DC really isn't it'. In the context of designing for 6GHz, it is. At 30MHz, 6GHz inductors are short circuit, capacitors are open circuits, just like they are at DC, and charge redistributes inside an HBT transistor like it doesn't above 100MHz, so it's only linear at high frequencies. Of course in the context of op-amps, 30MHz is very high frequency indeed.

AC and DC are meaningful distinctions when the context makes it obvious what you are talking about. They cease to be meaningful when you start to argue about how to define the terms.

Answer (score 1):

It is AC if it changes **periodically**.
It does not matter if the **period** is a year or a picosecond.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_current

> Alternating current (AC) is an electric current which periodically reverses direction

Comment: I would question wikipedia definition, at least in the electronics engineering field. We call AC a whole bunch of things, and many of them are not periodic, nor the current does change direction.

Comment: "we call AC a whole bunch of things" or do you mean we call a whole bunch of things AC?

Answer (score 0):

It greatly depends on your setup (circuit, power and signal sources, measurement instruments, environment, parasitic effects, etc.) and what you are attempting to do.

In a sense, DC doesn't exist (yep!), since even when you apply battery power to a circuit, in reality you are applying a step signal (0V before power-up and, say, 5V after), so it is not DC, *mathematically*!

Therefore, it all depends on the time scale of the events that your experiment (circuit) is involved into.

For example, an RC high-pass filter with a time constant of 1 year (let's say, R~30MΩ and C=1F supercap) will appear as passing DC for, say, the first couple of minutes after applying DC at the input, i.e. for time scales much less than its time constant.

Without more details from you it is impossible to give you a deeper answer.

Comment: I always hated that what constitutes DC varies from what I've seen. I was always told that it is only AC when you have a change in polarity, thus anything else is DC. In that sense, a square wave is DC, just a non-flat DC waveform.

Comment: @JarrodChristman It's just terminology, and it has some context-dependent variation too. For example, if you study digital signal processing or signal theory, it all makes more sense, from a mathematical POV. Even the definition of AC is more stringent in those fields: a time-varying signal is not necessarily AC, even if it is periodic. It must also have a zero mean value (i.e. zero DC component). In electronics sometimes we cut corners and say AC to mean any time-varying signal.

Comment: I've studied digital signal processing as well. I suppose I just dislike the use of words that vary in meaning by context... but maybe that's just me being a bit too strict ;-)
However, I understand what you mean. In signal processing, you get a DC component term of the signal, a flat fixed voltage, at least in that usage.